# Need checkbox to be checked when i click "+" in jsgrid

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

I want checked checkboxes when i need to insert a new row.

```
{ name: "isactive",
  title: "IsActive",
  type:"checkbox", 
  align: "center",
  sorting: false, 
  filtering: false},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `insertTemplate` of your checkbox field, so that it's checked:

```
{ 
    name: "MyField", 
    type:"checkbox", 
    insertTemplate: function() {
        var $result = jsGrid.fields.checkbox.prototype.insertTemplate.call(this);
        $result.prop("checked", true);
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Assuming "+" is in any button 
 $('#button_id').click(function(){
    $("#x").prop("checked",true);
 });
```

Moreover, You can check or uncheck a checkbox element or a radio button using the .prop() method like the following code.

```
 // Check #x
 $( "#x" ).prop( "checked", true );

 // Uncheck #x
 $( "#x" ).prop( "checked", false );
```

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about? u know jsgrid?

Comment: @AravindhGopi yes it is jquery plugin